# Comment visibility in open/libre office spreadsheets

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'm getting moderately perturbed by how difficult it is to see whether there's a comment in a cell in LibreOffice.  As it stands a tiny box appears in the upper right-hand corner in the cell.  Does anyone know of a setting/plugin to improve this?  I'm dealing with an enormous spreadsheet and lots of comments and I'm getting tired of squinting. >.<  To the degree that they differ, a solution for either LibreOffice or OpenOffice will do as I have access to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to modify the layout of the "comment indicator". But you can use the Navigator Window to quickly move between comments (you may toggle the "Navigator" using <kbd>F5</kbd> or menu `View` -> `Navigator`):

[image]

Another option may be to show the comments permanently; but you will have to toggle this for every comment, using the cell's context menu -> `Show Comment`.

Comment: That works and is about as close to an answer as I'm gonna get.  Many thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome :-) !